# Delete my old (and wrong) accepted answer

Tags: support, answers, deletion, accepted-answer

How do I delete this [old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1757041/229762)? Not only it's wrong but there's also a way better (and correct) answer [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1764950/229762).

**Note:** That answer is now moderator deleted.  The OP of the Question involved has not been on the site in more than a year.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Deleting my accepted answer and contacting the mod](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9271). (Although probably you are already aware that the problem is that your answer is accepted - otherwise you would be able to deleted it yourself.) And a related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Allow author of accepted answer to delete it in certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14932).

Comment: Since this answer (linked by the asker her) was deleted by a mod, the answer (duplicate?) certainly contradicts what happened here.  In fact, an accepted answer was deleted by a mod, @quid.  So it demonstrates that in fact, one can still manipulate circumstances so as to delete an accepted answer, despite what the supposed "duplicate" says.  Closed by quid as a dupe (this meta question), despite  proving the dupe is meaningless, after quid deleted the accepted answer.

Comment: @amWhy while generally accepted answers should not be deleted (or any useful answer for that matter) in relatively clear cut cases mods do intervene. The answer did not answer the question as asked, and this was pointed out there. Another answer there does answer the question as  asked. If it'd been reasonably possible OP should have kept OP in the loop, but given that they are long gone, there is likely not much point in trying. Whence I went ahead and removed it.

Comment: I was sloppy though in that I did not edit the other answer there and left a dangling ref, and, yes also the dupe target was not ideal. I added two more. The middle one, "How to delete an accepted answer" is the most pertinent one. There the same mod explains that we sometimes still might delete. Thanks for  having signaled the issue.  @amWhy

Comment: Thanks for the added info, @quid!

Comment: Kinda late, but thanks everyone!